# Datatable not working on ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I use Datatable in my web application. 
Following is my simple code to get data using ajax.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mytable').DataTable();
    } );
</script>

<body>
  <h2>AJAX SELECT</h2><hr>
  <div align="center">
    Select Team :
    <select name="select" id ='teamSelect'>
        <option value="">Select Value</option>
        <option value="op2">Company 1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id='tableContainer' align="center"></div>

 <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#teamSelect").bind("change", function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET", 
                url: "getData.php",
                "dataSrc": "tableData",
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#tableContainer").html(html);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

and Getdata.php Code

```
<table id="mytable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I Link Jquery, datatable css and js both.but still It return output as normal HTML table.
No console error founded.
I need that data in datatable. So how can i get that.

and i also tested datatable in index.php page. It working quite good.

Comment: Your question somewhat related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595717/bootstrap-datatable-not-working-after-loading-data-using-ajax-json).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are initializing datatable before table added. You need to initialize it in ajax

remove following script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mytable').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

update ajax as below:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#teamSelect").bind("change", function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET", 
                url: "getData.php",
                "dataSrc": "tableData",
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#tableContainer").html(html);
                    $('#mytable').DataTable({ 
                      "destroy": true, //use for reinitialize datatable
                   });
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its working Fine.But you add Extra bracket at  $('#mytable').DataTable(({

Answer (score 1):

Put

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

At the bottom of your `Getdata.php` file also links to the datatable css and js.

Or use ajaxComplete function() to call the datatable.